# mount any component in same app.js vue.js 3 laravel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I´m traying to mount any datatable in my `app.js` file:

```
require('./bootstrap');
import { createApp } from "vue";
import VueGoodTablePlugin from 'vue-good-table-next';
import 'vue-good-table-next/dist/vue-good-table-next.css'
import datatablePhysios from "./components/datatablePhysios.vue";
import datatableTreatment from "./components/datatableTreatment.vue";

const app = createApp(datatablePhysios) // here it´s the component
app.component('datatableTreatment', {
    datatableTreatment
});

app.use(VueGoodTablePlugin);
app.mount("#app")
```

i´m working with `laravel-9`.

My problem it´s that, always mount same component `datatablePhysios` it´s my first time with vue 3 i´m working with vue 2 and nevar had this problem.

**update** in vue 2 i did this:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('usuarios-component', require('./components/usuariosComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('formularioactualizacion', require('./components/datosUsuarios.vue').default);
Vue.component('listadoasistencias', require('./components/mostrarAsistencias.vue').default);
Vue.component('listadobonosdisponibles', require('./components/mostrarBonosDisponibles.vue').default);
Vue.component('listadoasistenciaspendientes', require('./components/mostrarAsistenciasPendientes.vue').default);
Vue.component('estadisticasusuario', require('./components/estadisticasUsuario.vue').default);
Vue.component('estadisticasadmin', require('./components/estadisticasAdmin.vue').default);
Vue.component('tablabusqueda', require('./components/tablaBusquedaAdmin.vue').default);
```

Thanks for readme and help me. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: `always mount same component datatablePhysios` ... well ... `createApp(datatablePhysios)` will do that - I have no idea what your end goal is, but if you show how you do it in vue2 then perhaps it'll become clearer

Comment: @Bravo thanks for your response. i updated my question with vue 2 code with any component. i want set any component in app.js to use in different blade. with vue 2 i can to do this with my code in update

Comment: Self-answers are welcome on SO. If you have a solution for your own problem, consider moving it from the question to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem nstantiate empty vue object and after created a component:

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp } from "vue";
import VueGoodTablePlugin from 'vue-good-table-next';
import 'vue-good-table-next/dist/vue-good-table-next.css'
import datatablePhysios from "./components/datatablePhysios.vue";
import datatableTreatment from "./components/datatableTreatment.vue";

const app = createApp({}) // here it´s the component

app.component('datatable-physios', datatablePhysios)
app.component('datatable-treatment', datatableTreatment);

app.use(VueGoodTablePlugin);
app.mount("#app")
```